# Modifications done not getting reflected in a CSS asset file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have an issue with my Rails 4 app, all my css files works fine except one called `webinars.css.scss` it won't apply change even if i delete all its content !!

for example i have a `<div class="one"></div>`, if i open any css file then i add `div.one{background: red}` my div's background change well, but if i add the same line (i mean div.one{background: red} ) to `webinars.css.scss` my `div.one` background still without any background color.

also if i delete all the content inside my `webinars.css.scss`, my page won't change !!

**all this means : either i add (or i delete) some change to webinars.css.scss, any of them will work**

i tried many things like remove the browser cache, also i restarted the server (i restarted my computer too), but with no result !

some one have any suggestion about what the problem can be ? if you want that i show you any file just tell me which one and i will show you

**Update :**

my application.css.scss include itself and all other files as well :

```
/*= require_self */
/*= require token-input-facebook */
/*= require_tree . */
```

also if i add any file (for example abcd.css.scss ) to my `assets/stylesheets/` with the style `div.one{background: red}` it works fine, then if i rename it to `webinars.css.scss` it won't works :/

Comment: Is it actually included in your page? And your folder /public/assets is empty?

Comment: Have you included it in your manifest file OR referenced with stylesheet_tag in the page?

Comment: yes it's included but its content still the same either i add or i delete some code from it, my public directory have no assets folder it contains just 404.html 422.html and 500.html

Comment: @RajeshCO yes my file is included

Comment: I hope you are in development environment only. So, assets will be there inside /app, /lib or /vendor directories. Does the stylesheet folder included in asset paths? Please check it in your console from the application root directory 'Rails.application.config.assets.paths'

Comment: You said your `stylesheets` folder contains only one file called `webinars.css.scss`, then where is you `application.css.scss` file?

Comment: @RajeshCO i mean by that, i haven't a double :D the problem is with this name "webinars.css.scss" read my update question please

Comment: @RajeshCO yes i'm in development environment only, assets folder exist in /lib but it's empty, before i tried to compile my css files manually then i removed /assets from the public directory :) i can't see where is the bug

Comment: You need to do precompilation in production mode only. So, no need to look in '/public/assets/', there will be nothing. Please check whether my answer can be of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `application.css.scss` and `webinar.css.scss` and `token-input-facebook.css` files are inside '/app/assets/stylesheets/' folder, then you need to change:

```
/*= require_self */
/*= require token-input-facebook */
/*= require_tree . */
```

To

```
/*= require_self
/*= require token-input-facebook
/*= require_tree .
```

and now if you call it with `<%= stylesheet_include_tag "application"%>`, it will work for you.

**Update:**
It could be because of the reason that you may have `compiled assets` inside your `public/assets` folder. Please remove all the precompiled assets. Actually, application will look for compiled assets first, i.e., in `public/assets` folder. So, better you remove the `assets` folder inside `public`. Run `Rails.cache.clear` OR `rake tmp:cache:clear` as precompiled assets once served would have been cached. Also, make sure in `development.rb`, have this line. `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`.

Then restart the server in development mode. Everything will work fine.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: all these files are inside /app/assets/stylesheets/, it's not problem of inclusion, the 3 files are well included, and i can check them in the source page :) the problem is the webinar.css.scss won't change either i add some styles to it or i delete from it, hope you understand what i mean

Comment: i already removed it from my public directory read my comment above, i ended up by rename my webinars.css.scss to webinars.css, then i reloaded the page, then rename it again to webinars.css.scss, this way it works ! i don't know why exactly but it solved my problem, thank you for help Rajesh, i don't know if you have any comment about that but i'm sure i already removed the navigator cache

Comment: Yes, it should have been the cache playing there. You had to run `Rails.cache.clear` OR `rake tmp:cache:clear`. Also, make sure in `development.rb`, have this line. `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`.

Comment: yes i have config.action_controller.perform_caching = false in development.rb :) it's the first time i hear about Rails.cache.clear command it's helpful thank you